# Circle appears as a square in IE

Tags: html, css

I have the following css code for drawing a circle on a page.

```
.full-circle {
 background-color: rgba(204, 0, 102, 0);
 border: 3px solid #333;
 margin: auto;
 height: 75px;
 width: 75px;
 -moz-border-radius:75px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
 }
```

It is called by:

```
 <div class="full-circle">
```

Works fine in Firefox but when I run it in IE it appears as a square and i'm not sure why.

Comment: Because you only specify mozilla and webkit specific border radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marvin pointed it out in the comments, but it is the answer to your problem: you have not specified the normal `border-radius`. Furthermore, if you're looking to create a circle, you want `50%`, not `75px`. `75px` may make your particular `div` a circle, but if you decide to make the `width` wider, it will render differently. Your CSS should look like this:

```
.full-circle {
   background-color: rgba(204, 0, 102, 0);
   border: 3px solid #333;
   margin: auto;
   height: 75px;
   width: 75px;
   border-radius:50%;
}
```

**EDIT**: As Rob pointed out, you probably don't even need the -moz and -webkit prefixes unless you are designing a website for a user-base you know uses older browsers. I removed them from the example.

Comment: Mozilla has not needed a vendor prefix for this since version 2. Chrome hasn't needed one since version 3. Non webkit browsers has needed this in many, many years

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments by Rob, most browsers have had [no need for vendor prefixes since 2010](https://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius), just add

```
border-radius: 75px;
```

IE8 did not support this property, IE9 supported it without the `-ms-` prefix.

But check out @Vector's answer, you should really be using `%` and not `px`

Comment: IE has not needed the vendor prefix since IE8. No other browser has needed them since forever. So there is (probably) no need to do any of this but `border-radius: 75px;` except for the issue mentioned by @Vector